# Using Matlab, how can I find the value K in the following root locus?

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, how can I find value of K, in a system that has oscillation?

> (system's tf, if needed:  (K * (s +
>   25))/(s^3 + 24 s^2 + 100 s) )

PS. I'm using root locus.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is the plant for a closed-loop system with gain compensation only (that would be K).  In that case I would express it as a transfer function and then use the root-locus command to see where it hits on the x-axis:

```
num = [1 25];
den = [1 24 100 0];

sys=tf(num,den)
rlocus(sys)
```

Unfortunately your system appears to be stable for all values of K!  Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Does the `dcgain` function do what you need?